# input file is output file suppress error or alternate method

Tags: bash, concatenation, xargs

This code block will replicate my issue.   I'm getting an "input file is output file" error when I concatenate a list of files.

The file concatenation works and the resulting $concat_file is exactly what I want.  I can't figure out how to suppress the error and it is filling up my mailbox as the job runs frequently.  Other posts recommended adding "|| true" but that did not work.

Any help on error suppression or alternative methods would be great.  Thanks

```
working_dir=~/files_for_concat
dt=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)
concat_file=$working_dir/$dt

mkdir $working_dir
cd $working_dir
echo "one" > one
echo "two" > two

find $working_dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
  sort -z |
  xargs -0 cat -- >> $concat_file

cat $concat_file
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes from the fact that `concat_file` is located inside `working_dir`; at a moment `find` will give `concat_file` to `xargs` which in turn will try to cat the file in himself.

The solution is to exclude `concat_file` from the search. For instance try this:

```
find $working_dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
  grep -v "$concat_file" |                       # This excludes the file
  sort -z |
  xargs -0 cat -- >> $concat_file
```

You may also improve the beginning of the script in this manner:

```
test -d "$working_dir" || mkdir "$working_dir"
cd "$working_dir" || exit 1
```

Comment: `-print0` means that a line does not correspond to a single filename in the output of `find`. `grep -v` will filter the wrong text.

Comment: thanks for the response Edouard.  I now understand that it is including the destination file and can create it in another directory.